# move the product detail section to footer container

Tags: layout

i've the following code in themename/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<div class="product-collateral">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional_info'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
</div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

i move above code in themename/template/page/html/footer.phtml, but it displays nothing, anyone know what are the problems?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot simply move this around in the .phtml files, because of dependencies.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
```

means that your template tries to render the block with the name  "info_tabs" which exists for the product view page, but probably not for your footer block.

To move all this content, you will need to update your layout as well (e.g. use a local.xml file in your theme).

EDIT: See here for an introduction of how layout / blocks and template interact: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates